# Remove specific line from txt file

Tags: java, javafx, text-files

Hello i need to delete a specific line from text file after ID search p.g. **ID=2**

> **students.txt**

```
1,Giannis,Oreos,Man
2,Maria,Karra,Woman
3,Maria,Oaka,Woman
```

And after search and delete to get:

> **students.txt**

```
1,Giannis,Oreos,Man  
3,Maria,Oaka,Woman
```

But is not working properly

**Code so far:**

```
    @FXML
    TextField  ID2;
    @FXML       
        public void UseDelete() throws IOException {
            File inputFile = new File("src/inware/students.txt");
            File tempFile = new File("src/inware/studentsTemp.txt");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            String lineToRemove = ID2.getText();
            String currentLine;

            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) {
                    continue;
                }
                writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        }
```

Comment: What is the result that are you seeing which is incorrect?

Comment: Does `ID2.getText()` equal `2,Maria,Karra,Woman`? Its name implies it would only contain `2`.

Comment: Yes, Andy Turner i have text field and i can put the ID p.g. `ID=2`

Comment: Ryan Pierce Williams i want to take the 2nd txt form (without 2nd line if i give ID=`2`)

Comment: The code is not delete anything now, just create `studentsTemp.txt` with the same lines

Comment: Change the check to something like `trimmedLine.startsWith(lineToRemove)`... Furthermore I do recommend using try-with resources to ensure the reader/writer is closed even if an exception happens. Furthermore i recommend using `writer.newLine()` instead of writing `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. The effect should be the same and by using multiple write operations you don't need to create a new string...

Comment: Try trimming also lineToRemove: `String lineToRemove = ID2.getText().trim();`

Comment: @fabian i made the changes you said, but it create a new empty studentTemp.txt file

Comment: Κούκλος ο Γιάννης

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a line by a line number I guess you can do a change to your code like this. You can give the int value of Id to the `lineToRemove` variable instead of my hard coded value

```
import java.io.*;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new A().useDelete();
    }

    public void useDelete() throws IOException {
        File inputFile = new File("src/inware/students.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("src/inware/studentsTemp.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        int lineToRemove = 2;
        String currentLine;
        int count = 0;

        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            if (count == lineToRemove) {
                continue;
            }
            writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        inputFile.delete();
        tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all Thanks for the help! It work, but is not replace the `student.txt` file just create a new one `studentsTemp.txt` with the changes.

Comment: @FoticPap Its how your code is written. But if you want to replace the student file, you just have to delete and replace the name of it. I have edited the code with changes. Use this edited one

Comment: `int lineToRemove = 2;` this cant work for me, because i need to check the string number i gave **(gives me bug)** so if i put ID=`2` delete the 2nd line ok but if after i want to delete 1st line ID=`1` delete the 3rd

Comment: Any way i found solution to my problem i change `int lineToRemove = 2;` to `int lineToRemove = Integer.parseInt(ID2.getText());`. Thanks for the help